# Why is the composition of convergent Laurent series convergent?

Tags: complex-analysis, riemann-surfaces, laurent-series

In Rick Miranda's book Algebraic Curves and Riemann Surfaces, the author proves the order of a meromorphic function $f \colon X \to \mathbf{C}$ at a point $p$ is independent of the complex chart that is used. To do so, he chooses charts $\phi \colon U \to V$ and $\psi \colon U' \to V'$ and substitutes the Taylor series expansion of the transition function $\phi \circ \psi^{-1}$ at $\psi(p)$ into the Laurent series expansion of $f \circ \phi^{-1}$ at $\phi(p)$. I was wondering why such a substitution produces a convergent series.

Answer (score 1):

The Laurent series of a **meromorphic** function is just a power series with a finite number of negative exponents. That is, a power series multiplied by negative power of the variable. This does not affect the convergence of the series.

Comment: "A Laurent series is just a power series with a finite number of negative exponents." That is not true. For example, consider  the Laurent series of $e^{1/z}$ about $0.$

Comment: The function $\,e^{1/z}\,$ has an essential singularlity at $0$ and hence is not a [meromorphic function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meromorphic_function).

Comment: I know that. But that's not what you had when I commented.

Comment: My answer was in the context of the question about "the order of a meromorphic function".